# javascript enable textbox on dropdown change event

Tags: c#, javascript

i have five dropdown and five texbox and I'm checking on click of any of the dropdown the corresponding texbox should get enabled/disabled through javascript am using master page in asp.net
e.g: if am selecting `dropdownlist1` then `texbox1` should get enabled,for one textbox its working how to make it work for five textbox

```
 function HideTextBox(ddlId) {
        var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);

        if (ControlName.value == 0)  
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtComment1.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtComment1.ClientID%>').disabled = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery, it is better way. Set two class to each textBox, first  .textBox1 .myTexts,
the first class must include an id for text boxes. Such as .textBox1, .textBox2 ect.  And your dropbox value must include just text box's id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dropBoxID").change(function(){
      $(".myTexts").attr('disabled','disabled');
      $(".textBox"+$(this).val()).removeAttr("disabled")
   });
});
```

Comment: i want to use javascript for it.

Comment: if you use ClientID  you have to define each one in your js code, you can use document.getElementById('<%=txtComment1.ClientID%>').setAttribute("disabled","disabled") and removeAttribute("disabled")

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/3WJtM/

```
function HideTextBox(ddlId) {  

    var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.getAttribute("id"));
    var idTxt = ControlName.getAttribute("txt");
        if (ControlName.value == 0)  
        {
            document.getElementById(idTxt).disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(idTxt).disabled = false;
    } 
}
```

on every object select, add an attribute txt with the name of te input text
In the javascript you search this textbox for enabled or disabled

for example

```
<select id="ddl1" txt="txt1"  onchange="HideTextBox(this);" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="input" id="txt1" disabled/>
```